# responsive images and different pic resolutions

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design, slider

i have this website, and as you can see on the index page that we have a 80% width and 100% container and in it a picture. Now there is a problem with different images and their resolutions, some are stretched some are narrow. 
I want the pic to be full screen size and 80% width and to have proper aspect ratio. I would probably need some javascript to crop the images? please i need some insights on how to do that. Also a slider can do the trick if it has cropping feature and the possibility of 80% width and 100% height

here is the url

http://tinyurl.com/otwocvz

Answer (score 1):

try removing the image and add the image as header2 background.

```
.header2 {
position: absolute;
z-index: -1;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background-color: #CCC;
display: block;
background: url(http://leowd.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/leowd-umbrella-red2.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
background-size: cover; }
```

Comment: i thied but it did not even display the picture. I probably need some java script slider that can do that for me. because the pictures are different sizes and they come out differently by my percentage set (80 100) 

if you check now u can see the container and the gray color isperfect but the picture is not full width, even if u try to strech it and do it full height the aspect ratio goes wrong

Comment: i've changed the css again --- for some reason your server are blocking images requests. try one more time with this sample image placed >> http://postimg.org/image/kdczc9lqx/

Comment: its not displaying the pic :/